# OpenCv Shape Dectection

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using Opencv to detect shapes and size of material( like disc, washers, nuts and bolts of different size)  on that will be held on running belt. what function would be best to distinguish between them.
I am planing to use cvFindContours( to find the shapes) and cvArcLength & cvContourArea to get their area.

Any better approach ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple approach to shape matching:

1. Convert to grayscale
2. [Smoothen](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html) the image.
3. Apply some [morphological operations](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html) (if necessary).
4. [Edge detect](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#canny)
5. Find contours (the same you mentioned). The contour function is hierarchical. Hence, segmenting the required (outer in most cases) contour(s) should be easy. Disc and washers can be distinguished by the hole in the contour hierarchy.
6. Use [ApproxPolyDP](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=moments#approxpolydp) to get your contour to a rough regular shape. You might be able to distinguish the shapes based on the vertex count in the contour.
7. Use [moments](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=moments#moments) to distinguish the shapes if ApproxPolyDP is not sufficient.

It works for most cases. Always provide sample images to help us assess the complexity of the problem :D.

Answer (score 0):

Check for haar cascade object detection technique in opencv 
here are some links....

http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html

http://www.technolabsz.com/2011/08/how-to-do-opencv-haar-training.html

For working with haar cascade u need haar kit for traing purpose..

http://kineme.net/files/haar.zip

Comment: unfortunately, all of it quite outdated (restricted to the old haarcascade format). since a couple of years, there's CascadeClassifier/opencv_traincascade, which can read/produce hog and lbp cascades as well.

Comment: hmmm right that kit is for the same purpose above links are just for the sake of knowledge how it actually works.

Comment: yea, ok. no downvote or such. just reminding (since your answer will be out here *forever*)